# Ubuntu 20.04: Can't upgrade Virtualbox: "A copy of VirtualBox is currently running"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Virtualbox 6.1.8 from the official Oracle repository. When I try to upgrade to 6.1.10 I'm getting the following error:

```
A copy of VirtualBox is currently running.  Please close it and try again.
Please note that it can take up to ten seconds for VirtualBox to finish running.
```

Nothing unusual - I ran into this frequently in the past. But as far as I can tell this time there are no running VMs (the following command doesn't print anything):

```
$ VBoxManage list runningvms
```

I rebooted my machine but that didn't help either. Any ideas what I can do to troubleshoot?

Details about the packages:

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox-6.1
virtualbox-6.1:
  Installed: 6.1.8-137981~Ubuntu~eoan
  Candidate: 6.1.10-138449~Ubuntu~eoan
  Version table:
     6.1.10-138449~Ubuntu~eoan 500
        500 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal/contrib amd64 Packages
 *** 6.1.8-137981~Ubuntu~eoan 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I can't find any lock files - neither in `/var/lib/virtualbox` nor anything related to Virtualbox in `/var/lock`. The Google search you suggested didn't provide any insight either.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo service vboxdrv stop
```

helps me, from here https://github.com/buguroo/cuckooautoinstall/issues/8#issuecomment-258797788

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux and thanks for sharing your answer! Unfortunately, I don't have the system around anymore to verify your answer. But your answer makes sense to me. Looks like a regression to me (without any VMs running it used to shut down without any manual intervention).